# Log base e versus log base 10 for semilog plot, how do I recognize the type of curve my data fits?

Tags: logarithms, data-analysis

If I have a curve (with some noise) that looks like logarithmic growth, how can I find out whether I should use Log base 10 or Log base e on the y axis in order to estimate a linear fit on the semilog plot?

Comment: I just realized there is a problem with my question. I realized that taking the semilog plot is for exponential growth, not logarithmic growth. Also, if I have data that looks like logarithmic growth (y=a*ln(b*x)), but it intersects the axis at (0,0) instead of (1,0), how can I check whether it looks like logarithmic growth (but shifted to the left) or whether it is more similar to something like a square root or logistical growth curve (logistical growth has an asymptote, my data may or may not.). Is there a good resource I can read at looking at data and seeing what type of curve it fits?

Answer (score 1):

Any logarithm is just a constant multiple of the natural logarithm. We can see this by the change of base formula $\log_a(x)=\frac{\log(x)}{\log(a)}$, with the logarithms on the right being any base. Basically, $\log_{10}(x)=\frac{1}{\log(10)}\log(x)$, so the only difference the choice of base for your logarithm is the scaling, which you can change after.

So choose whichever you'd like.